# Why can the address of an array variable can not be assigned to a pointer? And what are  'Wfatal-errors'?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I tried the below-pasted code and got an error:

> cannot convert `int (*)[6]` to `int*` in assignment
>   compilation terminated due to `-Wfatal-errors`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_array[] = {1,23,17,4,-5,100};
int *ptr;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    ptr = &my_array;     /* point our pointer to the first
                                      element of the array */
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      printf("my_array[%d] = %d   ",i,my_array[i]);   /*<-- A */
      printf("ptr + %d = %d\n",i, *(ptr + i));        /*<-- B */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `ptr = my_array;` or `ptr = &my_array[0];`?

Comment: yes i want to experiment and understand thats why i did ptr = &my_array;

Comment: Why somebody has vote it down?I am new to this and learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ptr = &my_array;
```

The type of `&my_array` is `int (*)[6]` while the type of `ptr` is `int*`. They're incompatible types.

What you should be doing is this:

```
ptr = my_array;
```

Now the type `my_array` is `int[6]` which decays into `int*` in the above context. So it works.

Answer (score 2):

An array is convertible to a pointer. What you meant to do is:

```
ptr = my_array;
```

Comment: "An array is convertible to a pointer so a pointer to an array is convertible to a pointer to a pointer". That doesn't follow, and isn't true. A pointer-to-array is not convertible to a pointer-to-pointer (except by a reinterpret_cast, and doing that would be broken). Consider, "a float is convertible to a double, therefore a pointer-to-float is convertible to a pointer-to-double". Nope.

Comment: -1. It is incorrect >> *"[...] a pointer to an array is convertible to a pointer to a pointer"*

Comment: @SteveJessop and Nawaz, thanks for the correction, removed wrong assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use:

```
ptr = my_array;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
ptr = &my_array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is:

```
ptr = my_array;
```

There's no need to use the `&` operator.